# Intellij not recognizing wrong return type

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this method:

```
public <T extends CacheResult> T get(Object key, CacheDefinition cacheDefinition) {
    return load(key, cacheDefinition.name(), cacheDefinition.getTypeReference());
}
```

Now my IDE complains (as expected, and which is correct) about this line, because the return type is supposed to be **CacheResult**

```
User user = spxCacheManager.get(username, CacheDefinition.USERS_BY_USERNAME);
```

What I currently dont understand, is that the IDE (IntelliJ) is **not** complaining about this:

```
List<User> usersFromCache = spxCacheManager.get(username, CacheDefinition.USERS_BY_USERNAME);
```

Which is actually wrong. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because `T` gets inferred as an intersection type - `List<User> & CacheResult & Object`. After all, why can't a class both implement `List<User>` *and* implement/extend `CacheResult`? Such a type is certainly possible!

You can see this happen by writing a toy program and using the `--debug=verboseResolution=all` option:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> u = new Main().get();
  }

  public <T extends CacheResult> T get() {
    return null;
  }
}

interface CacheResult {}
class User implements CacheResult {}
```

`javac` with `verboseResolution=all` would output:

```
  instantiated signature: ()INT#1
  target-type: List<User>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends CacheResult declared in method <T>get()
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,List<User>,CacheResult
```

You can also follow through [the process of how Java does type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html). Eventually (somewhere in "resolution"), you'll reach a point where you need to find the *greatest lower bound* ("glb") of `Object`, `List<User>` and `CacheResult`, and that type is exactly their intersection type, as defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).

On the other hand, your code won't compile if `CacheResult` is a class, and the type you are assigning the method result to is an unrelated class, since no class can inherit from two unrelated classes.