# Why can I assign to a concrete type that doesn't implement type-parameter interface bound of the returned type

Tags: java, generics

Can someone help me understand why the code below compiles:

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Concrete c = foo();
  } 
  public static <T extends Interface> T foo() {
    return null;
  }
  interface Interface {}
  static class Concrete {}
}
```

In my mind, `Concrete c = foo()` should not compile since `T` is bound to `Interface` only and not guaranteed to be `Concrete`.

If I switch `null` to `(T) new Interface() {}` it sill compiles with unchecked warning (on the return expression inside `foo()`, not on `Concrete c = foo()`). Obviously it gives me a `ClassCastException` when executed.

Comment: Interesting. How are you compiling that code? Chances are it's a compiler bug. I can reproduce it in Eclipse... whereas explicitly specifying the concrete type argument `Concrete c = Main.<Concrete>foo()` fails... Well, can reproduce it in jshell too (OpenJDK 17).

Comment: I would expect it to pass compilation because `Concrete` is not *final* (a subtype could well implement `Interface`), but even with a final class, it doesn't fail.

Comment: Even stranger, the compiler will not let me use `return new Interface() {};` as the body of foo().

Comment: @VGR *that* compiler error would be justified, because `new Interface(){}` is not compatible with `T` in all cases... a cast would be required, just as the OP had to do it.

Comment: @ernest_k Ah, I see your point.

Comment: @ernest_k [The spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4) doesn't seem to consider final-ness when resolving bounds during type inference, so the behaviour does follow the spec, but I do agree that it _should_ consider final-ness though.

Comment: [This should answer the first half of your question about `Concrete c = foo()` compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69886931/5133585).